# Flatten nested arrays in cosmosdb sql

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following cosmosdb document:

```
{
  id: "id",
  outer: [
    {
      "inner": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
    },
    {
      "inner": [ "d", "e", "f" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I need to create a SQL request which would return all of the combined values of the "inner" arrays, like this:

```
{
   "allInners": [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
}
```

I was able to unwind the first array level using the "IN" operator, but I am not sure how unwind it one more level and to handle double or even triple nested arrays.
The following is my subquery to aggregate those items

```sql
SELECT
  ... other stuff.
  ARRAY(SELECT VALUE innerObj.inner FROM innerObj IN c.outer) AS allInners,
  ...
FROM c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this sql:

```
select ARRAY(SELECT VALUE e FROM c join d in c["outer"] join e in d["inner"]) AS allInners from c
```

Here is result of my test:
[image]

Hope this can help you.:)

Comment: get each item in inner array,and put them into a new array.You can run the sql:`SELECT c,d,e FROM c join d in c["outer"] join e in d["inner"]` to look at documents look like.More details, you can refer to [arrays and objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions) and [joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join).

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution to my problem (using the nested "IN" and a subquery):

```sql
ARRAY(
   SELECT VALUE inner
   FROM inner IN (
      SELECT VALUE outers.inner
      FROM outers IN c.outer
  )
)
```